# Passing CLI arguments to a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script that contains several functions. One of the functions should receive command line arguments. Here's a similar script to what I'm doing:

```
$mydocs = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")

function example() {
  Param(
    [string]$name = "testfolder", 
    [switch]$foo = $false
  )
  $newdir = $mydocs + "\" + $name
  if (!(Test-Path $newdir)) { mkdir $newdir }
}
example
```

So when I run this:

```
.\example.ps1 -name anewfolder -foo
```

I want the function example to use these arguments.

Because of scoping, my function has no `$args`. I put `Write-Host $args` into the function to double check, and it returns nothing. How can I pull the parent args, pass them into params, and get example to run with my arguments? Or should I just remove the function and run this part of my code in the parent scope?

Comment: To do it this way, you'd have to add the same `param()` set to the top of your script and then call the function (as you are doing) with the params specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments to your script, you need to capture them in a `Param()` block like your Function has.  Alternatively, you can access script args with a scope selector like `$script:Args`.

```
Param([String]$Name,[Switch]$Foo)

$mydocs = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")

function example
{
  param(
    [string]$name, 
    [switch]$foo
  )
  $newdir = Join-Path $mydocs $name
  if (!(Test-Path $newdir)) { mkdir $newdir }
}
example -Name $Name -Foo
```

Now, `.\example.ps1 -name anewfolder -foo` will be successful.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The questioner wants the function to use the  arguments that are passed into the script. Your answer just hard codes the value for $foo. If you call the script as ".\example.ps1 -name anewfolder", the function will still see $foo as $true.

Answer (score 1):

`$args` inside the function is a different variable than `$args` in the global scope of the script. A very simple way of passing arbitrary script arguments to your function is to [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) `$args`:

```
example @args
```

Note, however, that this isn't a very clean approach. It'd be better to properly parameterize the script and selectively pass those parameters that are meant to go to the function, as [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920170/1630171) suggested.

```
Param(
    [string]$name,
    [int]$bar,
    [switch]$foo
)

function example() {
    Param(
        [string]$name = "testfolder", 
        [switch]$foo
    )

    $newdir = "${mydocs}\${name}"
    if (!(Test-Path $newdir)) { mkdir $newdir }
}

$params = @{}
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('name')) { $params['name'] = $name }
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('foo'))  { $params['foo']  = $true }

example @params
```

Comment: In contrast to @TheIncorrigible1, your answer is correct. But I wish there was a simpler way, similar to his answer, which would correctly pass not only $name but the switch $foo.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz Well, you could simply do `example @PSBoundParameters`, but that would pass through *all* parameters given to the script, not just the ones that are valid for the function. Meaning a parameter `-bar 42` would also be passed to the function, which may or may not cause problems, depending on the rest of the code.